# How to read the asc file generated using writeRaster in terra by VB6?

Tags: r, ascii, raster, terra

I can use VB6 to read the values of the ASC file generated by writeRaster in raster in R. However, the ASC file generated by writeRaster in terra cannot be read by VB6 by value or by line. It can only read the entire file using either "Input" or "Line Input" function. Any help would be appreciated.